# react-native-date-picker app crash in certain screen

Tags: react-native, datetime, npm

For some reason my app crashes when trying to pick date with react-native-date-picker.

I have a re-useable component for the datepicker and I am using it in 2 different screens. On one screen it works without any issues and on the other screen it crashes when I try to pick a date/time.

CustomDatePicker.js

```
class CustomDateTimePickerModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: new Date(),
        date:Moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),      
        mode: 'datetime',
        time: Moment(new Date()).format('HH:mm'),
    };
  }

  handleDatePicked = value => {
    const dateCheck = new Date()
    if(dateCheck.getTime() > value.getTime() ){
        this.setState({
            value: new Date()
        })
    }
    else{
        this.setState({
            value
        })
    }      
  
   };

  savePickedDateAndTime = () => {
    const date  = Moment(this.state.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
    const time = Moment(this.state.value).format("HH:mm")
    this.setState({ 
        date,
        time,
       });
    //api call to fetch data with date and time
    this.props.sendDateAndTimeToParent(date,time)
    this.hideModal()
   
  }
  
  hideModal =() => {
    this.props.sendModalVisibiltyToParent(false)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
            <Modal visible={true} transparent={true} statusBarTranslucent={true}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.hideModal} style={{position: 'absolute', backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', bottom: 0,width: '100%', height:'100%'}}>
              </TouchableOpacity>
      
                <View style={{position: 'absolute',flex:1, bottom: 0, width: '100%', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                    <DatePicker
                        date={this.state.value ? this.state.value : new Date()}
                        mode={this.state.mode}
                        onDateChange={this.handleDatePicked}
                        is24hourSource={'device'}
                        />

                      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: 120, justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop:5, marginBottom:5}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.savePickedDateAndTime} style={{margin:10}}>
                              {vMarkFilledIcon(mainColor.secondaryColor, 32)}
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.hideModal} style={{margin:10}}>
                              {cancelIcon(cancelButton.color, 32)}
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                      </View>                     
                </View>
          
            </Modal>
        </>         
    );
  }
}
```

Results.js

```
//imports 

 getDateAndTimeFromChild = (date, time) => {
    //api call to fetch data with date and time
    this.setState({
      date,
      time
    },
    () => {
      this.arrangeSearchCriteriaParameters()
    })
  }

  changeModalVisibilityFromChild = (isVisible) => {
    //clean all date data that is left
    this.setState({
      show: isVisible
    })
   }


render() {
    return (

//...

 {this.state.show ? 
                <CustomDateTimePickerModal
                  sendModalVisibiltyToParent={this.changeModalVisibilityFromChild}
                  sendDateAndTimeToParent={this.getDateAndTimeFromChild}
                />
                 : 
                 null}  
   )
}
```

OtherScreen.js

```
  changeModalVisibilityFromChild = (isVisible) => {
    //clean all date data that is left
    this.setState({
      show: isVisible
    })
   }


  getDateAndTimeFromChild = (date, time) => {
    //API call to get the estimated arrival time 
    
    this.setState({
      date,
      time,
    })
  }

render(){
    return(
    //....

 {this.state.show ? 
                <CustomDateTimePickerModal
                  sendModalVisibiltyToParent={this.changeModalVisibilityFromChild}
                  sendDateAndTimeToParent={this.getDateAndTimeFromChild}
                />
                 : 
                 null}  


   )
}
```

For some reason the Results.js datepicker works but the one in OtherScreen.js does not.

Am I missing something??

UPDATE:

Adding some errors seen:

```
05-23 19:09:01.645  4021 23926 W GmsLocationProvider: Error removing location updates: 16
05-23 19:09:01.791  1747 24952 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
05-23 19:09:02.281 24955 24955 W cmd     : Can't find service car_service
05-23 19:09:02.842 24568 24568 E InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
05-23 19:09:02.842 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find JSIModule for class UIManager
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModuleRegistry.getModule(JSIModuleRegistry.java:24)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getJSIModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:564)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:90)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:46)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManagerForReactTag(UIManagerHelper.java:40)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.handleEvent(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:505)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.onEventDispatch(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:483)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcherImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatcherImpl.java:116)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.uimanager.JSTouchDispatcher.handleTouchEvent(JSTouchDispatcher.java:74)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostView$DialogRootViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(ReactModalHostView.java:497)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2609)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:465)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:861)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:423)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13674)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5285)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7630)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 E MessageQueue-JNI:      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
05-23 19:09:02.845 24568 24568 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.joyride_client, PID: 24568
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find JSIModule for class UIManager
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModuleRegistry.getModule(JSIModuleRegistry.java:24)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getJSIModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:564)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:90)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:46)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManagerForReactTag(UIManagerHelper.java:40)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.handleEvent(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:505)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.onEventDispatch(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:483)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcherImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatcherImpl.java:116)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.JSTouchDispatcher.handleTouchEvent(JSTouchDispatcher.java:74)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostView$DialogRootViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(ReactModalHostView.java:497)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2609)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:465)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:861)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:423)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13674)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5285)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7630)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
05-23 19:09:02.849 24568 24568 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
05-23 19:09:02.854  2008  4762 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.joyride_client/.MainActivity
05-23 19:09:02.857  2008  4762 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
05-23 19:09:02.872  2008 24959 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
05-23 19:09:02.857  2008  4762 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) Binder:2008_19 identical 8 lines
05-23 19:09:02.858  2008  4762 W InputReader: Device has associated, but no associated display id.
05-23 19:09:02.881 24568 24568 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 24568 SIG: 9
05-23 19:09:02.882  2008  2040 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
05-23 19:09:02.883  2008  2040 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
05-23 19:09:02.886  1754  1933 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 21944832 , only wrote 21807712
```

Answer (score 1):

I built this ugly code, it's not ideal, but it works

The components below the datepicker (touchableOpacity) overwrite onClick in the region where the App crashes:

```
<View>
  <DatePicker
    style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
    mode='date'
    date={this.state.dataReport}
    onDateChange={this.setDate}
  />
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{ position: 'absolute', marginTop: 0}}>                                      
    <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>SOME CONTENT</Text>                                                                  
  </TouchableOpacity> 
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{ position: 'absolute', marginTop: 155}}>                                      
    <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>SOME CONTENT</Text>                                                                  
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

I tried this solution because this problem is still open, see component github!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using getstureEnabled:true remove it in nativagor Screenoptions i struggled to find it . but that was my case .

explanation my case (in navigation v5+ if you have the option gstureEnabled set to true then remove it . because in some android devices it collides with picker libraries (not just date) example : so when you try to spin date the app crashes . because in that screen either the screen or navigator has gestureEnbled set to true somehow this collides with the navigation deep on the java levels).